# Best way to debug haproxy errors?

Tags: haproxy

I am looking for a useful way to debug haproxy errors..

I found the "log-separate-errors" option (nice feature, because we have thousands of request per second and do not want to log them all), but the log message is not very helpful in our case, since the request is missing.
I tried it with the socket command "show errors" which is called periodically by a script, but with this I only get the last few errors and if there are many errors between one period the error I am looking for could be missing.

So is there a way to get a full log with the request (as with the "show errors" socket command) when an error occurs?

Thanks a lot for your answers.